# Unable to switch back to lightdm default settings

Tags: xfce, lightdm, xfce-panel, xfce4-terminal

Installing the lightdm on ubuntu20.04, after that I changed some configurations on themes and panels.

Becuase I found that the panels modified by me was somewhat ugly, So I tried to switch back t

to the default setting.

But no luck

then I tried to remove xfce4 and lightdm using

```
sudo apt-get remove lightdm xfce4 xfce4-support
sudo apt-get purge lightdm
I even deleted the /etc/lightdm dirctory.
```

But no luck, when I log into the lightdm it still didn't go back to the default settings.

I'd appreciate if you can give me some advice to change my lightdm to default settings, especially the pannel. It is so ugly that I can not even stand it with a minute!

Thank for you time.